# how to detect the text out of HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have following html line of code

```
<span class="navbar-text navbar-nav company-title">aLine</span>
```

aLine is the text on navigation bar. How can I find this text via xpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can select it directly by the class name:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("navbar-text navbar-nav company-title")).then(function(elements){
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath could look like this:

```
//span[@class='navbar-text navbar-nav company-title']/text()
```

Comment: This syntax is not acceptable for Selenium as XPath should return elements only

Comment: @Andersson The question was about XPath and how to retrieve the text. Haven't seen the tags though.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution:

```
var element = document.querySelector("[class='navbar-text navbar-nav company-title']");
var text = element.innerText;
```

Yo may want to check element is null

```
element != null ? element.innerText : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this as xpath, if you wish to identify the Web Element that contains this text "aLine":

```
//span[text()='aLine']
```

Or, if you want to extract the text out of the Web Element, you can use the technique mentioned by @Andremoniy above.

Answer (score 0):

To find the text **aLine** you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//span[@class='navbar-text navbar-nav company-title']
```